# How can I run Lua through the terminal WITH file path?

Tags: cmd, lua, command-prompt

I have added lua's interpreter to path and it works with file names but I can't run lua through the terminal with file path. I am looking for a way to run lua through the terminal with the file path. I've encountered this while making a macro to automatically run lua files. My macro to run lua in Visual Studio Code uses this argument in keybindings:

```
"args": { "text": "lua '${file}'\u000D" }
```

I have tried the command of `lua D:/Downloads/Useful stuff/code/lua/a.lua` but I'm getting the error: `lua: cannot open D:/Downloads/Useful: No such file or directory`. I have tried that command both without and with '', both of them don't work.

Comment: Try `"args": { "text": "lua \"'${file}'\"\u000D" }`

Comment: @ESkri that didn't work but when I removed the ' ' in ${file}, it works! Thanks so much! Here is what works:`"args": { "text": "lua \"${file}\"\u000D" }` .

Comment: Your command should read as ```lua "D:/Downloads/Useful stuff/code/lua/a.lua"``` , instead of ```lua D:/Downloads/Useful stuff/code/lua/a.lua```